# CORS issue in ionic with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ionic-framework, cors

I'm trying a sample project with `ionic` and backend as `Rails`. When I start ionic server using ionic serve and submit my sample form am getting

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/signup. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.`

Tried some of the answers which I got in google but couldn't get though it. 
Below is my app.js code index.html and ionic.project files code.

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.constant('ApiEndpoint',  'http://localhost:3000/')

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('signUp',{
    cache: false,
    url: "/signUp",
    templateUrl: "templates/signUp.html",
    controller: 'ExampleCtrl'
  }) 

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/signUp");
})

.controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope','$http','ApiEndpoint', function ($scope, $http, ApiEndpoint) {

  $scope.registrationForm = {};

  $scope.signUp = function(){
    console.log($scope.registrationForm);
    console.log(ApiEndpoint);
     $http.post(ApiEndpoint + "signup", {a: 1}).then(function(result){
       console.log(result);
       $scope.registrationForm = {};
     }, function(error){
       console.log(error);
       $scope.registrationForm = {};
     })
  }
}])


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-nav-bar class="nav-title-slide-ios7 bar-stable">
        <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-bar>
      <ion-nav-view>
      </ion-nav-view>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>

</html>

{
  "name": "kranthi_web",
  "app_id": "",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http:localhost:3000/"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone tell me where am I doing wrong please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) policies are designed to prevent XML requests for different domains' assets.

Basically, if you're requesting a resource from a different domain/server through XML, you'll need to make sure you have the respective CORS policy on that server to handle it.

---

Rails, by default, prevents any external XML request from being responded to. The only way to fix it is to allow the resource through your own CORS policies.

The [`rack-cors`](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) gem is the best for this:

```
#config/application.rb
# ...

config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

If you set the above for your domain (IE localhost or whatever), you should be able to access your backend from your front-end JS.

... and remember that using Angular / other JS type framework, you're going to be sending XML requests every time.

Comment: But I wanted to send Json requests instead of XML. So may I know what should be done for that case please

Comment: I think the JSON request will still be going through the XHR request type. You should try the code I provided to see if it works. If it works, then you can work out how to get it to be JSON

Comment: Sure. Thanks alot! :-)

Comment: Let me know what happens - we need to get this working

Comment: Definitely. and I don't need any extra configurations on Ionic side, right?

Comment: Ah!!!.. Working..Thanks alot!..Tried lot of answers and spent lot of time. Thanks alot for that!!!

Comment: I'm trying to reuse my Ionic mobile app for web as well with rails and was facing this issue..thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

In your base controller you should provide the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

```
   class Api::BaseController < ActionController::Base

      before_action :cors_preflight_check
      after_action :cors_set_access_control_headers

      protected

      def cors_preflight_check
        if request.method == 'OPTIONS'
          headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
          # ...
        end
      end

      def cors_set_access_control_headers
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        # ...
      end
    end
```